# Internet Service Error on Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime on dot net 6

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

i attempt to migrate bot framework composer dot net 3.1 project to dot net 6

upon testing i hit Internet Service Error, any insight would be appreciated.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'adaptiveDialogId')
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialogBot..ctor(string adaptiveDialogId, string languageGeneratorId, ResourceExplorer resourceExplorer, ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, SkillConversationIdFactoryBase skillConversationIdFactoryBase, LanguagePolicy languagePolicy, BotFrameworkAuthentication botFrameworkAuthentication, IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient, IEnumerable scopes, IEnumerable pathResolvers, IEnumerable dialogs, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime.ConfigurationAdaptiveDialogBot..ctor(IConfiguration configuration, ResourceExplorer resourceExplorer, ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, SkillConversationIdFactoryBase skillConversationIdFactoryBase, LanguagePolicy languagePolicy, BotFrameworkAuthentication botFrameworkAuthentication, IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient, IEnumerable scopes, IEnumerable pathResolvers, IEnumerable dialogs, ILogger logger)
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, ref Span arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method8(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: You appear to be getting an `ArgumentNullException`, so you might want to debug your code to determine where that occurs and why the `adaptiveDialogId` is null, or what it's supposed to be. If you can then provide more information, we might be able to help you. You should be able to modify the build target and update packages, but that might depend on your implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks AP01 for dropping your knowledge

Unfortunately, the adaptiveDialogId is embedded in library Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime in which I cannot debug

however, inspired by your advice

I modify the build target not from scratch, but simply upgrade the dot net target straight from 3.1 to 6

as it turns out the problems caused by nullable validation in the Project File, this causes dot net 3.1 libraries not working

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    **<Nullable>enable</Nullable>**
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```